# Makefile, modify list

Tags: string, list, makefile

If I have a list in a GNU Makefile, is it possible to create a new list with the original strings modified. This is would be perfect if there was the `map` higher-order procedure from some languages.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do

```
DIRS=A B C D
#apply some magic to create
DIRS_INCLUDE=-IA -IB -IC -ID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've said it's GNU Make:

```
DIRS_INCLUDE=$(foreach dir,$(DIRS),-I$(dir))
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html#Foreach-Function